# flawfinder - 2 errors overflow buffer (char,strlen)

Tags: c, security

I'm trying to figure out how to solve 2 hits in a program,but I cannot understand how...

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXSIZE     40
void test(char *str) {
    char buf[MAXSIZE];
    if(strlen(str) > MAXSIZE)
        return;
    strlcpy(buf, str);               
    printf("result: %s\n", buf);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *userstr;

    if(argc > 1) {
        userstr = argv[1];
        test(userstr);
    }
    int i[10];
    int j = 0;

    while (j < 10000)
    {
        i[j] = 5;                
        ++j;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < sizeof i / sizeof i[0]; ++j)
        printf("Value = %d\n", i[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

And I got these 2 hits:

```
C:\Users\vord\codetest\test1.txt:5:  [2] (buffer) char:
  Statically-sized arrays can be improperly restricted, leading to potential
  overflows or other issues (CWE-119!/CWE-120). Perform bounds checking, use
  functions that limit length, or ensure that the size is larger than the
  maximum possible length.
C:\Users\vord\codetest\test1.txt:6:  [1] (buffer) strlen:
  Does not handle strings that are not \0-terminated; if given one it may
  perform an over-read (it could cause a crash if unprotected) (CWE-126).
```

The first hit I trying to understand it, because the MAXSIZE is already set to 40 ,it's already limited...
The second hit I searched for solution, but I found things that don't work...

I will be very glad if you could help me to figure out how to fix these hits.

Comment: If it *didn't* complain about `int i[10];while (j<10000){i[j]=5;++j;}`, you overpaid for flawfinder.

Comment: [`strlcpy`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcpy&sektion=3) needs a size argument `size_t dstsize`. That's *three* arguments.

Comment: if `strlen(str) == MAXSIZE`, `strlcpy` will copy `MAXSIZE+1` bytes.

Comment: @scottHunter I changed the strlcpy(buf, str) to strlcpy(buf, str,sizeof(buf)), 
I chnaged the number of iterations to j<10 , about the strlen you mean to chnage if(strlen(str) > MAXSIZE) to if(strlen(str) == MAXSIZE)?

Thanks for the replys.

Comment: No; you want to reject calls where the string is too big to fit in the buffer, no matter how too big it is.

Comment: remember that flawfind (and it's cousing RATS) are basically grep on steroids...they do not do dataflow or control flow analysis.  The first finding is simply saying the character buffers might be over run, and you, as the programmer, need to be sure that you have taken precautions to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

The `strlen()` function returns the length of string not counting trailing '\0', so you need to declare buffer with size equal to `MAXSIZE + 1`.
Additionaly, to ensure that the `buf` will be zero terminated (what is needed for `printf()` call), simply initialize `buf` with 0. In that case this is the cheapest solution.

Try this:

```
void test(char *str) {
    char buf[MAXSIZE + 1] = { 0 };
    if (strlen(str) > MAXSIZE)
        return;
    strlcpy(buf, str, MAXSIZE);               
    printf("result: %s\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful comment :)
I understood my mistake, the strangest thing that the flawfinder is still showing the same problem that I need to put some functions to limit length, the same error like in the post on the lines:
char buf[MAXSIZE + 1] = {0};
if(strlen(str) > MAXSIZE)